# Where is the 'TypeError: Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed' coming from?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function

I am defining the following loss function:

```
smooth = 1.0
def loss(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true_f = K.flatten(y_true)
    y_pred_f = K.flatten(y_pred)
    if K.sum(y_true_f) == 0 and K.sum(y_pred_f) == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        intersection = K.sum(y_true_f * y_pred_f)
        return (2. * intersection + smooth) / (K.sum(y_true_f) + K.sum(y_pred_f) + smooth)
```

This works but, when I change line 4 to `if K.sum(y_true) > 0 and K.sum(y_pred) > 0:` I get a TypeError as mentioned in the question title.

Anyone can let me know what is going on? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Right, tensorflow works by first compiling a graph of all of the operations that are going to get done. It's similar to how Java and C++ have to compile the code first, and then run it separately. Due to this, you can't have a python if-statement in the tensorflow code, since there aren't actually any numbers there while it's compiling, so it won't know which of the routes to follow.

In order to account for this, you need to write up the code without any python if-statements. This is often easier said than done, but it luckily seems pretty straightforward in your case using a `tf.where` call. My code sample is in tensorflow since that's what I know, but it should hopefully be easy to extend it to keras.

```
total = tf.abs(tf.reduce_sum(y_true_f)) + tf.abs(tf.reduce_sum(y_pred_f))
divisor = tf.where(tf.equal(total, 0), 1, total)
# Now we can divide cleanly
return (2. * intersection + smooth) / (divisor + smooth)
```

Comment: I see! but this wouldn't return 1 when K.sum(y_true_f) == 0 and K.sum(y_pred_f) == 0! it just sets divisor to 1. Or am I missing something?